# CIFilter blending mode that results in only bright, saturated colors in Swift

Tags: swift, blending, cifilter, compositing

I'm using the CICategoryCompositeOperation CIFilter category in attempt to apply an effect to an image that results in only displaying bright, saturated colors and removes everything else including black and white, and colors below a certain brightness. This may involve other filters as well.

Then need to lay this over an other image, so the top resulting image needs to be to either transparent where it cuts everything out, or use a background color like black that works with a certain blending mode to blend those two images together.

Comment: You've shown no attempt to sovle your problem. At the very least, have you tried making a mockup in Photoshop?

Comment: I was worried about that. I tried all the CIFilters in the  CICategoryCompositeOperation category.

Comment: This would be two questions in two days with (all told) two lines of code. No offense intended, but how can anyone help you without such details? *"This may involve other filters as well."* Huh? I don't understand. Treat me as a stupid newbie who has learned some areas of `CoreImage`. What do you mean by this? Can you give me (us?) something that (a) can be duplicated, (b) behaves in the way you are seeing, and (c) tell us in *specific* detail related to the example you need to provide what you expect the results to be?